# Access the data from the multiple files using C

Tags: c, file

wanna access multiple files using C.

For suppose, I have file with that names

- 1.txt
- 2.txt
- n.txt

I am looping through all of the files till n. But I am only getting data from the first file which is 1.txt. and that data is repeating n times. (n represents the number of files).

So, how to get data from each file. Each file contains different data.

```
for(i = 0; i < fileQuantity; i++) {
        sprintf(buffer, "%d", i);
        ptr = fopen(strcat("C:\\TURBOC3\\FILES\\", strcat(buffer, ".txt")), "r");
        fscanf(ptr, "%s", &adminUsername);
        fclose(ptr);
        outtextxy(225, 140 + distance, adminUsername);
        distance += 30;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised that you can read even from one file :). `strcat("C:\\TURBOC3\\FILES\\",` will not work as it invokes Undefined Behaviour (attempt o modify string literal, access out of bounds).

Simply do:

```
        sprintf(buffer, "C:\\TURBOC3\\FILES\\%d.txt", i);
        ptr = fopen(buffer, "r");
```

or better

```
snprintf(buffer, buffer_length, "C:\\TURBOC3\\FILES\\%d.txt", i);
```

I would suggest using something more modern than TurboC 3 :) (at least from this century)

Comment: actually my university uses that old software -_- that's why I have to use that

Comment: Thank you alot :-) It worked

Comment: @HashimAbbas Then upvote and accept

Comment: it says you need 15 reputation to case a vote